# How to setup Eclipse for Wowza module debug on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, debugging, wowza

Anyone have some tutorial/instructions on how to setup Eclipse to debug wowza custom module on Mac?

I've tried adding this in the "properties" => "Run/Debug" => "Arguments"

```
-Dcom.wowza.wms.native.base="osx"
```

If there's some sample tutorial on how to do this I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to install the [WowzaIDE](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?759-How-to-extend-Wowza-Streaming-Engine-using-the-Wowza-IDE) within the eclipse platform. Ensure that your build path -> libraries section includes all the jar files that are standard with your latest install of wowza (those that reside in the [wowza-install-dir]/lib/ folder).

Once installed, you can debug the custom module by adding log lines to it which will appear in your [wowza-install-dir]/logs/wowzastreamingengine_access.log.

Ex.

```
WMSLoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("YourModuleName[function] debugging message..");
```

If you want to be more specific with when the log message shows up, you can use getLogger().error(..) or getLogger().debug( ... ).

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Not that. I want to use debugger on custom module with breakpoints. I've set it on Linux before, but Mac wont work. It just stays at connecting to server...

Comment: Oh I see.  Did you try to start from within Wowza using Debug->[your-profile] ?  What do you get for errors/output in the console?